# Two transformers connected to boiler, no A/C

Tags: thermostat, boiler, transformer

My HBSmith boiler honeywell circuit box has a 2-wire from transformer to the thermostat. Then there is another transformer on the ceiling that has conduit to the same circuit box, but different terminations in the circuit box. From the transformer on the ceiling a 2-wire cable also goes to thermostat but not connected. I can’t imagine what this other set of wires do, and if they should connect to my thermostat.

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your boiler please, or at the very least a model number?

Answer (score 0):

When I started in the HVAC field in the late 1960's it was common to mount the furnace transformer on a ceiling joist or on the side of the furnace, whatever your choice, since most installations were for heat only and required just 2 or 3 wires depending on the type of furnace controls used. Today, furnaces have integral transformers and control boards that control a bunch of devices.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like one of the transformers is not being used.